# How to order a softlayer network gateway with ssh configured for Gateway and its member

Tags: go, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, gateway

How to order a softlayer network gateway with ssh configured for Gateway and its member

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/datatypes"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/sl"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    // SoftLayer API username and key
    username := "set me"
    apikey   := "set me"



    // Build a Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Disk_Image object containing the order
    // you wish to place
    order := datatypes.Container_Product_Order{
        ContainerIdentifier: sl.String(d.Get("hostname").(string)),
        Quantity:            sl.Int(1),
        Hardware: []datatypes.Hardware{
            {
                Hostname: sl.String(d.Get("hostname").(string)),
                Domain:   sl.String(d.Get("domain").(string)),
            },
        },
        Location:  sl.String(strconv.Itoa(*dc.Id)),
        PackageId: pkg.Id,
        Prices: []datatypes.Product_Item_Price{
            server,
            os,
            ram,
            portSpeed,
            priIpAddress,
            remoteManagement,
            vpnManagement,
            monitoring,
            notification,
            response,
            vulnerabilityScanner,
        },
    }

    // Set SSH Key on main order
    ssh_key_ids := members[0].Get("ssh_key_ids").([]interface{})
    sshKeyP := make([]int, len(ssh_key_ids))
    for i, ssh_key_id := range ssh_key_ids {
        sshKeyP[i] = ssh_key_id.(int)
    }
    order.SshKeys = make([]datatypes.Container_Product_Order_SshKeys, len(members))
    order.SshKeys[0] = datatypes.Container_Product_Order_SshKeys{
        SshKeyIds: sshKeyP,
    }

    // Create a session
    sess := session.New(username, apikey)

    // Get SoftLayer_Product_Order service
    service := services.GetProductOrderService(sess)

    // Use verifyOrder() method to check for errors. Replace this with placeOrder() when
    // you are ready to order.
    receipt, err := service.VerifyOrder(&templateObject)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\n Unable to place order:\n - %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Following helps to print the result in json format.
    jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(receipt, "","     ")
    if jsonErr != nil {
            fmt.Println(jsonErr)
            return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```

This is the script I am using to order, but it configures the ssh keys only for the gateway member but not the gateway. could you please help me on how to configure the ssh key for gateway and its member. It would be great if you could update the same script and share it.

Answer (score 0):

SoftLayer Network Gateway is an object which consists of either one member (standalone) or 2 members (High Availability). When you accessing a gateway via ssh, it actually establishes ssh session with one of gateway member.  So you can only configure ssh key for gateway members, not gateway itself.